# Suddenly, my Mac's display in every application has a severely restricted color-space

Tags: color

MacBook Pro, Big Sur latest version.

All of a sudden, every display of every image – in every application, from Finder to Photos to web-browsers – even the screen-saver display – looks like it came from the 1980's.  "About 32 different colors in all."  And yet, the desktop display does not immediately look very-wrong.

The problem, whatever it is, appears to affect every application uniformly.  Anytime anything wants to display "a photo," it appears to have very few colors to choose from.  And yet, the desktop display appears the same as it always was.

Is this some global hardware/OS setting, or do I need to take my computer in for servicing?

~ Experienced Mac user

Comment: P.S.: It now appears *very specifically(!)* that this problem manifests when the computer is displaying an image or a movie.  And, no matter what application it might be, the effect is the same. It now affects everything including the screen saver but it does so uniformly.  Imagine that the monitor can display about 32 colors and you see what I mean. And yet, outside the image square, everything appears perfectly fine.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem, but maybe not. Screenshots would really help as would the model number of your MacBook Pro.

Comment: MacBook Pro 2017. This problem first began to appear just a few days ago. For instance, the "choice of user icons" screen shows this problem, but when you select the user, the next screen doesn't.  "Photos" shows an image with this problem, but the surrounding display doesn't. (Well, actually, the "circular photo for this user" DOES.  Videos do the same. The problem even appears when you click on a media file in the Finder.  No ... this must be some kind of a SETTING.  But, where is it?!

Comment: To clarify:  "Login Window" ... the entire display has this effect.  Click on a user, and you see a perfectly-normal-looking desktop display – yet the icon for the chosen user is affected.  Log on and everything looks just fine ... until you try to look at an image or a movie in whatever context.  Then, it looks like your color palette has been squashed.  I don't know how to provide a screenshot.

Comment: Also:  just a few days ago, my USB keyboard gave out and I had to use my Macbook Pro's built-in keyboard with its very-weird top bar until the replacement gear arrives.

Comment: I wish that you could see it:  every time, everywhere, "an image" is supposed to be displayed, the computer now presents a severely color-flattened image, AND(!) the image visibly "flickers!"  I have utterly no rational explanation for what I am now seeing.  If I "copy the image to the clipboard and paste it to TextEdit," it looks exactly the same. So, this must be some SYSTEM-LEVEL problem – and yet, my desktop looks fine.

Comment: I hate mystery problems like this too, but to have a chance at help that is beyond just speculation, you're going to have to add screenshots. The old classic `Shift + Command + 3` for a full screen screenshot or `Shift + Command + 4` for an adjustable size screen screenshot should work and put the files on your Desktop for easy uploading, too.

Comment: All right then, but how then do I make such a thing visible to you?  The bottom line here is that every single image displayed by an application behaves as though we were suddenly back in the 1980's where every device had a very small "color palette."  And yet, the desktop looks just fine.  THIS *MUST* BE A 'SETTING!'  But I still have no idea where!

Comment: You can edit your answer to include images.  In the editing dialog box, look for a small icon that looks like a picture of mountains.  You'll be able to upload the images there.  I recommend a screenshot of a colorful image from a publicly accessible website, so we can compare the files you post to what the rest of us can see.  [Here's a suggestion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Male_adult_Gouldian_Finch.jpg)

Comment: Just added a picture from a political website – but it could be anything.  The color palette is, as you see, virtually gone: it looks as though there might be no more than 32 or 64 shades in the whole thing.  Also – I've concluded that the "Color Utility" doesn't appear to have anything to do with it.  Basically, anytime we see a picture or a movie, this is what I get.  As of day before yesterday.

Comment: **Please note** That maybe *YOU* see "a perfectly normal picture!"